# postgres sometimes doesn't update data

Tags: postgresql

```
create table foo (a text);
create table bar (b text);

insert into foo (a) values ('1');
insert into bar (b) values ('1');

select * from bar;

with _ as (update bar set b = '2' from (select * from foo for update) as foo returning b) update foo set a = '1';
select * from bar;

with _ as (update bar set b = '2' from (select * from foo for update) as foo returning b) update foo set a = '1' from _;
select * from bar;

with _ as (update bar set b = '3' from (select * from foo) as foo returning b) update foo set a = '1';
select * from bar;

with _ as (update foo set a = '1') update bar set b = '4' from (select * from foo for update) as foo;
select * from bar;
```

Why didn't the first request update bar, although the others did?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can claim this is a full answer but it's far too long for a comment, so...

It's fairly obvious that the `FOR UPDATE` on the inner clause is the interesting part here, in conjunction with the fact that nothing outside the clause references any of its rows.

If we reduce your examples and look at their plans:

```sql
\echo 'No locking...'
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
with _ as (update bar set b = '3' from (select * from foo) as foo returning b) update foo set a = '1';
 
\echo 'Locking...'   
EXPLAIN ANALYZE          
with _ as (update bar set b = '2' from (select * from foo for update) as foox WHERE true OR bar.b = foox.a returning bar.b) update foo set a = '2';
```

```
No locking...
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Update on foo  (cost=236.26..238.62 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.050..0.051 rows=0 loops=1)                                 │
│   CTE _                                                                                                                       │
│     ->  Update on bar  (cost=0.00..236.26 rows=18496 width=44) (actual time=0.030..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)                      │
│           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..236.26 rows=18496 width=44) (actual time=0.019..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)                  │
│                 ->  Seq Scan on bar  (cost=0.00..2.36 rows=136 width=6) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)             │
│                 ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3.04 rows=136 width=6) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)                 │
│                       ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..2.36 rows=136 width=6) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1) │
│   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..2.36 rows=136 width=38) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)                          │
│ Planning Time: 0.155 ms                                                                                                       │
│ Execution Time: 0.356 ms                                                                                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(10 rows)

Locking...
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                 │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Update on foo  (cost=238.98..241.34 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.053..0.055 rows=0 loops=1)                                              │
│   CTE _                                                                                                                                    │
│     ->  Update on bar  (cost=0.00..238.98 rows=18496 width=94) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=0 loops=1)                                   │
│           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..238.98 rows=18496 width=94) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=1)                               │
│                 ->  Seq Scan on bar  (cost=0.00..2.36 rows=136 width=6) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)                          │
│                 ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..5.76 rows=136 width=56) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)                             │
│                       ->  Subquery Scan on foox  (cost=0.00..5.08 rows=136 width=56) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)             │
│                             ->  LockRows  (cost=0.00..3.72 rows=136 width=38) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)                    │
│                                   ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..2.36 rows=136 width=38) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1) │
│   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..2.36 rows=136 width=38) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)                                       │
│ Planning Time: 0.175 ms                                                                                                                    │
│ Execution Time: 0.147 ms                                                                                                                   │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(12 rows)
```

I don't know if you've ever looked at PostgreSQL explain output, but other readers won't have, so the bit we are interested here is the actual output (starting `actual time=`) and in particular the number of rows output `rows=`.

Comparing the two you can easily see that the `Subquery scan`/`LockRows` are only in the second example and that they return 0 rows. This means you have a join against zero rows with `UPDATE bar set b ... FROM` so no update of bar.

So far, so concrete. The question then of course is "why?" and here I'm going to have to speculate a bit.

You have two clauses running an `UPDATE` on foo in the same query. Both clauses will lock the same rows, but (I'm pretty certain) only one of them will actually take any locks. It doesn't make sense for one statement to have multiple locks on the same rows, so one of those two is going to skip the locking.

I think what happens now is two different effect come together. Firstly - the planner/optimiser can see that we don't actually use any of the columns returned from foo. So - it decides it can get away with just taking the locks and counting rows at which point... Secondly those rows are already locked so nothing happens and it returns a count of zero (rows locked, which is not the same as rows selected for locking).

This might be some corner-case of intended behaviour, but it feels like an actual bug (which is a hard thing to find in PostgreSQL). If nobody better informed than me comes along here, I would recommend contacting the "general" mailing list listed on the postgresql.org site. The developers are on there and one will be able to clear this up for you.